# Element-wise addition of lists in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, vector, aggregation-framework, addition

I have a set of documents each of which has a vector field:

```
'vector':[x1, x2, ..., xn]
```

How do I perform element-wise addition of all `'vector'` fields?

My final goal is to get average `'vector'` field for collection subset.

I am using aggregation framework to `$match` a certain subset and then `$unwind:vector` for this subset. Next step is to perform element-wise addition and division by document count and I don't know how to do that.

---

Subset of collection:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "vector" : [
                1,
                2,
                3

    ]

}


{
    "_id" : 2,
    "vector" : [
                3,
                2,
                1

    ]

}
```

Expected result:

```
avgVector:[1+3, 2+2, 3+1]/2 = [2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Can you show us your document with the expected  result?

Comment: @Michael, here it is. I've simplified the case to the minimum

Comment: Do vectors always have same length?

Comment: @evilive, yes they do!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this because `n = 3`, where `n` is the length of the vector. I don't believe that you can perform element-wise addition of the vectors with that document structure, in general. There's no way to directly combine the vectors, but if you unwind them, you don't, in general, have a way to combine like components.

However, we can hack it when the length of the vector is 3:

```
db.vectors.aggregate([
    // put a $match here if you want to consider a subset
    { "$unwind" : "$vector" },
    { "$group" : { 
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "first" : { "$first" : "$vector" }, 
        "last" : { "$last" : "$vector" },
        "v_sum" : { "$sum" : "$vector" }
    } },
    { "$group" : {
        "_id" : null,
        "avg_first" : { "$avg" : "$first" },
        "avg_last" : { "$avg" : "$last" },
        "v_avg" : { "$avg" : "$v_sum" }
    } },
    { "$project" : {
        "avg_first" : 1,
        "avg_last" : 1,
        "avg_middle" : { "$subtract" : [{ "$subtract" : ["$v_avg", "$avg_first"] }, "$avg_last"] }
    } }
])
```

We can pick out the first and last components because `$unwind` will preserve the order of the array. We can average those and subtract the average from the average sum of all the components to get the average of the middle component.